# Finding constants making function continuous

Tags: calculus

> Determine the values of $h$ and $k$ so that
> $$F(x)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{kx^2-kx+x+10}{x^2-4}, &x\neq2,\\
> 3x+h, &x=2
> \end{cases}$$
> is continuous on $[0,4]$.

I extracted $k$ as Common factor and analyzed the difference between two squares for denominator and the numerator in denominator $(x+2)(x-2)$ and in the numerator $(x-2) (x+5)$  we get $\frac{x+5}{x+2}$ when $x=2$ we have $\frac{7k}{4}$ And I found $h=-6$ so R.H.S=L.H.S we have $7k/4=-6$ we get $k=-24/7$  it's true what do you think?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I extracted k as Common factor and analyzed the difference between two squares for denominatior and the numerator in denomator (x+2)(x-2)

Comment: It's a good idea to include your attempts when you ask a question! I'd recommend editing your question to include your own work to avoid downvotes

Comment: Your attempt is completely unclear (to me at least): where does your (x-2)(x+5) comes from? and your \frac[x+5][x+2]? and your \frac[7k][4]? and your h=-6?

Comment: /frac[k((x^2-x)+x-10][(x-2)(x+2)]

Comment: This answers none of my questions.

Comment: You need Mathjax tutorial.

Comment: Someone fixed the mathjax errors before I got to them. LOL.
@AnneBauval

Comment: @nickalh The OP's bad formatting was not a problem for me, and my questions to them remain unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

If we write the main function of the given piecewise function in the form
$$\frac{kx^2-kx+x+10}{x^2-4}=k+\frac{1-k}{x+2}+\frac{2k+12}{x^2-4}$$
everything becomes clear.

The trick is to write the numerator as
$$k(x^2-4)+(1-k)(x-2)+4k+2(1-k)+10.$$

Answer (score 1):

You should use the definition of continuity at a point $a$. That is, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. The problem point is $x=2$ since this is where the function may be discontinuous.

We want $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=f(2)=6+h$. Note that everywhere but $x=2$ we have that $f(x)=\frac{kx^2-kx+x+10}{x^2-4}$. So we want to find $k$ and $h$ such that $\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{kx^2-kx+x+10}{x^2-4}=6+h$.

To compute the limit, we want to factor $x^2-4$ into $(x-2)(x+2)$ to see which one is creating the issue. We notice the denominator goes to zero as $x\to 2$ because of the $(x-2)$ term. This is what we want to factorize out.

Therefore, use algebraic long division to find $kx^2-kx+x+10=(x-2)(kx+k+1)$ and we get that the remainder from this process is $12+2k$ which we want to be equal to zero. Therefore, $k=-6$. We can now compute the limit:

$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{-6x^2+7x+10}{x^2-4}=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{(x-2)(-6x-5)}{(x-2)(x+2)}=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{-6x-5}{x+2}=\frac{-17}{4}=6+h$. Therefore, $h=\frac{-41}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a function $f$ is continuous at $a$ if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$.  For your specific function, this means:

$$\lim_{x\to 2} F(x) = F(2)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{kx^2-kx+x+10}{x^2-4} = 6 + h$$

Performing polynomial long division on the LHS gives:

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \left( k + \frac{(1-k)x+4k+10}{x^2-4} \right) = 6 + h$$

Let's apply partial fraction decomposition to the remaining fraction:

$$\frac{(1-k)x+4k+10}{x^2-4} = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{x+2}$$
$$(1-k)x+4k+10 = A(x + 2) + B(x-2)$$
$$(1-k)x+4k+10 = (A + B)x + 2A - 2B$$
$$A + B = 1 - k; 2A - 2B = 4k + 10$$

Solving this system of equations gives $A = \frac{k}{2} + 3$ and $B = -\frac{3k}{2} - 2$.  So,

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \left( k + \frac{\frac{k}{2} + 3}{x-2} + \frac{-\frac{3k}{2} - 2}{x+2} \right) = 6 + h$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2} \left( k + \frac{k + 6}{2(x-2)} - \frac{3k + 4}{2(x+2)} \right) = 6 + h$$

In order for the term with $x-2$ in the denominator to not go to infinity as $x\to 2$, we need its numerator to be zero, i.e., $k = -6$.  Making this substitution gives:

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \left( -6  + \frac{7}{x+2} \right) = 6 + h$$

And since the LHS is continuous at $x = 2$, we can just plug that in.

$$-6  + \frac{7}{4} = 6 + h$$

From which straightforward algebra gives us $h = -\frac{41}{4}$.  In summary,

$$\boxed{h = -\frac{41}{4} = -10.25 \\ k = -6}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ne2$, $F(x)=\frac{P(x)}{(x-2)(x+2)}$ has a limit as $x\to2$ iff
$$0=P(2)=2k+12,\text{ i.e. }k=-6.$$
When $k=-6$, $P(x)=-6x^2+7x+10=(x-2)(-6x-5)$ and
$$\lim_{x\to2}F(x)=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{-6x-5}{x+2}=-\frac{17}4.$$
$F$ is therefore continuous iff $k=-6$ and
$$-\frac{17}4=F(2)=6+h,\text{ i.e. }h=-\frac{41}4.$$